# Ubuntu 18.04 Encrypted External USB Drive

Tags: usb, password, encryption

I recently updated from 64-bit 16.04 to 64-bit 18.04 on my laptop with an internal hard drive. I use a encrypted external hard drive for routine backups but when I enter the password to decrypt the drive, I get the following message:

```
Error unlocking /dev/sdb: Failed to activate device: Operations not permitted
```

I backed up before I upgraded, so I know that the saved password in my password manager was valid, but following the upgrade, it will not decrypt. I have tried the suggestions listed in other posts, but I am now wondering if it is related to my password length, which is 128-characters. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Encrypted how ? with what ?

Comment: The Ubuntu 16.04 disk encryption tool using the GUI.